# Laravel 5.5, routing depend of session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm starting to learn laravel 5.5 and I'm trying to create routes depending on the session

My code in web.php is:

```
if(session()->has("user")){
 Route::any('/profile/view',"ProfileController@view");
}

if(session()->has("admin")){
    Route::any('/game/new', "gameController@new");
}
```

but it don´t works, it show me "page not found".
How i can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RouteServiceProvider` are booted before the `StartSession` middleware, so you cannot access session in route files. Use `middleware` to check instead.

```
Route::middleware('session.has.user')->group(function () {
    Route::any('/profile/view',"ProfileController@view");
});

Route::middleware('session.has.admin')->group(function () {
    Route::any('/game/new', "gameController@new");
});
```

To create middlewares:

```
php artisan make:middleware SessionHasUser
php artisan make:middleware SessionHasAdmin
```

Update middlewares to check the session, if it does not have corresponding session, abort the request:

**app/Http/Middleware/SessionHasUser.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(session()->has("user")) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return abort(404);
}
```

Install Middlewares, so routing can use the middlewares

**app/Http/Kernel.php**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
        'session.has.user' => , \App\Http\Middleware\SessionHasUser::class,
        'session.has.admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\SessionHasAdmin::class,
        ...
    ],
```

Comment: the last part should go to the $routeMiddleware array, not in $middlewareGroups..
with your code Laravel will search for a class "session.has.user" which doesn't exists.